# How does "Cities in Motion" compare to "Transport Tycoon"?

Tags: cities-in-motion

I feel like buying Cities in Motion, but still not sure...  Many years ago I loved to play a game called Transport Tycoon and I want to play something that looks like it. How does "Cities in Motion" compare to "Transport Tycoon"? in terms of feature?

Please note that this is not a game recommendation, I don't want to know if it's "cool" or how the gameplay is, I just want a feature comparison.

Comment: There is a free open-source version of Transport Tycoon Deluxe called [OpenTTD](http://www.openttd.org/en/).
As the [website](http://www.openttd.org/en/) says:
> It attempts to mimic the original game as closely as possible while
> extending it with new features. If you want a game similar to the original transport tycoon, why not try it?

Comment: OpenTTD puts the fear in me. ive just never managed to understand it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Cities in Motion, you don't transport goods. And you don't transport between cities. The game is about managing a metro system within one city. A lot of the time you're building routes on roads that already exist (for trams and busses). You can build a metro system underground, and you can use boats to make river routes.

On top of that there are specific numbers of people to transport - you can see how many are waiting at each bus stop. The game is mostly about trying to prevent huge queues from growing and to make money. On the roads you have to deal with the fact that there is a lot of car traffic slowing down your busses.

Those are the major differences I can think of.